# Shiny in R: How can I send a number from server to ui?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

For layout reasons, I try to send a single number (number of plots for example) form server to ui. Moreover, I'd like to use this number then to define the width of a box.

Is this possible? And if, how? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help you, but you can give it a shot: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/server-to-ui-variable

Comment: Or see `?renderUI`

Comment: There is the Javascript way https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Comment: Yes @NBATrends is right , the simplest approach would be to change your UI a bit so that you're using renderUI

Answer (score 1):

I think if I understand correct, you would want to achieve the following:

1. Input Field in ui sends a value to server.
2. Server processes that, and generates a resulting value
3. The generated value from step 2 goes back to become a part of another input field or probably same input field as Step 1.

You could do something like this in the server:

```
shinyServer(func = function(input, output, session) {
    field1_options <- reactive({
       if (!is.null(input$field1)) {
          method1(input$field1)
       } else {
          method2(input$field1) 
       }
    })

    observe({
       updateSelectInput(
       session,
       inputId = "field2",
       choices=field1_options())
    })
}
```

What this does is simply use the value from field1 to calculate and populate field2, here i've used example of Select Input.

Comment: @ sigmabeta. Thank you very much for your answer. This sounds very promising. What do you exactly mean with method1 and 2? How would the ui-side look like? I assume this is just a simple selectInput, which gets updated?

Comment: Ui yes, it would be a select Input. Method1 and 2 would be custom functions you define on how to use the select input value and what to display. For eg, reading values from a csv file, and then later fetching from some other data frame in method2